# How to generate golang client with openapi generated flatest FastAPI

Tags: swagger, fastapi, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

I have a FastAPI application with the following versions:

```
fastapi==0.103.1
pydantic[email]==1.10.12
```

SDK generator used: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Command used to generate client:

```
openapi-generator generate \
      -p enumClassPrefix=true \
      -i "xxxxx" -g go -o "xxxxx" \
      --additional-properties generateInterfaces=true,packageName="xxxxxx",packageVersion="xxxx"\
      -p enablePostProcessFile=true
```

The goal is to generate golang, python client sdks from the openAPI generated by the application.
However, the openapi generated by the latest fastAPI has constructs like anyOf, oneOf, allOf which is not supported by the tool.

Is there a way to workaround this problem? Thanks a lot for your time

Things I tried:

1. Tried with latest version of openapi generator tool, but does not seem to work.
2. Downgraded openapi version to 2.x and tried constructs remain the same in the latest fastapi version